# Make calls between C++ and C# code

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, c++-cx

I am porting my game to Windows Phone 8. The Visual Studio project created by cocos2d-x has a C++ project called **MyGameComponent**, which is a dependency for a C# project called **MyGame**. In **MyGame**, cocos2d-x supplies you with a `LocalizedStrings.cs` file. I want to be able to call that file so that I can use the native localisation system. How can I do this?

I also want to use this for other functionality, so please don't suggest an alternate way to do localisation.

I am using cocos2d-x v2.2.5.

Comment: Are you using native c++ or are you using managed c++?

Comment: What's the difference? I'm guessing native.

Comment: Well the difference is that in managed c++ you can call .Net, in unmanaged (native) you cannot.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I'm in managed C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a delegate from your C# to the C++ Component.

In your C++ Component you'll define a delegate and a method call to set that delegate, like this:

```
public delegate Platform::String^ GetTranslatedStringDelegate();

public ref class Component sealed
{
  public:
  void SetDelegate(GetTranslatedStringDelegate^);

  private:
  Platform::Agile<GetTranslatedStringDelegate> m_delegate;
}
```

Then in your C# you can create a function that matches the delegate signature, and pass it down to your component:

```
public string GetTranslatedString()
{
   return "translated string";
}

// elsewhere in your C# code
component.SetDelegate(GetTranslatedString);
```

Then in your C++ you can just invoke the delegate method whenever you need to get a translated string.

Edit: I wrote a blog post about this topic - http://robwirving.com/2014/07/21/calling-c-methods-c-winrt-components/

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a go now.

Comment: OK, got it working! Now my question is, how do I let the C# code and the C++ code use the same component? At the moment I've made it a singleton but that's not the best code design.

Comment: You could new it in the C# and hang on to the ptr as a member variable, and in the C++ assign 'this' to a global ref ptr from the c'tor. Not sure if this is best practice, but it has worked for me.

Comment: Too much effort. It works and, considering that nothing serious depends on this design, I'll cut my losses. Thanks so much for this!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Managed c++ then you just need to add your C# dll as a reference in your C++ project.
Then just call your C# Dll as normal.

```
ManagedCSharp::ManagedClass::ShowValue();
```

Where ManagedCSharp is the Namespace, ManagedClass is the Class and ShowValue is the method.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to a cyclical reference? The C# code is in **MyGame** while I need to make the call in **MyGameComponent**, which is a dependent project of **MyGame**.

Comment: So add MyGameComponent to your C++!

Comment: **MyGameComponent** *is* the C++ project.

Comment: @robwirving Don't downvote my answer as the Asker specified he is using Managed.

Comment: @GuyKogus If Rob is correct that Windows8 doesn't use Managed c++ then what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Windows Phone uses C++/CX which is fully native, not C++/CLR which is managed.

Comment: In that case should I remove the `clr` tag?